# Table with an optional foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'd like to create a table with an optional foreign key. There isn't always one because it should be possible to store manual input (other are from checkboxes). Are the follwing tables correct (not completely)?

```
table_food
- name
- calories
- fs_name
...

table_name
- name
- fs_calories

table_calories
- calories
```

The form I created contains checkboxes to select a food. There is option for manual input. If I enter a food manually, I should be able to insert the calories as well because the database doesn't know each food. So in this case there is no foreign key to the table `table_calories`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What foreign key are you referring to?  What do the tables have to do with your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated my question :)!

Comment: there is nothing like this, a foreign key has rules that don't fit, so why do you exacrly want a checkbix the be refered

Comment: @nbk The reason is that I don't want to save all entries individually. For example if multiple user select a specific food it's pretty unnecessary to save the SAME calories all the time (e.q. banana = 89 calories).

Comment: then you save it as int and depending on position it is on or off, but this would afford an quite simple algorithm to encode and decode, which would as much trouble as to save individual checkbox values.

Comment: @nbk Can you give me an example? :)

Comment: see https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/datarepresentation.html 1 checked 0 unchecked

Comment: @nbk So you mean I have to add a new column to `table food` called `manual`? And if `manual` is 1 I know that the input was manual added and is not referred from another table?

Comment: you add a column with integer if you have checked uncheched checked uncheched you save 10 1010 (bit)  checked checked checked unchecked you save 14 and so on,l when you want to display the values you get from the database is 10 so the first checkbox is set second unset third set and fourth unchecked. more checkboxes you have you have to increase the numbers.16 checboxes need 16 bits to represent them

Comment: @nbk alright, but I don't know how many checkboxes I have because an admin can add them (using a form)..

Comment: dynamic is always problematic, because you have to identify the checkbox, so the apporach with the integer is no usable, still your database gets complicated, because you need a unique id (for the foreign key a column to identofy the chekcbox and the valu, maybe some more